# Running select filename from dbo.sysfiles returns short foldernames with tilde

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I am running the following statement in SQL Server 2014(in Windows 2012R2):

```
select filename from dbo.sysfiles where fileid = 1
```

However it returns:

```
c:\progra~1\micros~1\mssql1~1.sql\mssql\data\master~1.mdf
```

I wish for the full path without the tilde.

(e.g `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQL2014\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf`)

I tried upgrading the SQL Server 2014 Express to 2016 Express but it made no difference.

Any ideas?
Thanks.
Dave

Comment: Time to read the documentation - this is an obsolete system table (now view)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the non-deprecated equivalent [`sys.database_files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view's column `physical_name`, does it provide you the full path?

Comment: I will try it when I go back as it's not my server, thanks for the info. The main problem is this is running embedded in some c# code so I wanted to avoid rebuilding/re-releasing the code and wanted to know why the tilde was appearing as it does not appear with this on any other SQL instance I have tried

Comment: FWIW, I tried your query and I did *not* get the short name. I.e., I'm not convinced that this is because you use sysfiles. Still, don't want to use the old views, but just as a FWIW. So, first step would indeed be to see what sys.database_files says. Long or short name, and then take it from there. (The OS version *might* be a factor here. My thinking is that perhaps with older os sysfiles show short name, but short names aren't in newer os? Thinking out loud here...)

Comment: Yes i was thinking it was possibly O/S. There is something on the server I think, as I have tried this on another Windows 2012R2 and a Windows 2008 R2 server and it works perfectly (shows the long name)

Comment: TiborKaraszi I concur, I also didn't run into the issue with the deprecated view but don't know enough about the OS side to be able to speculate what is going on. @dave If you right click on your **database** (in SSMS) and then click **Properties** and go to the **Files** page, what do the file paths look like in there for your database files?...Perhaps this *shortcut* file path was used during initial creation of the database?...if so, perhaps you can **carefully** change the path to the fully qualified path in the database properties' **Files** page, and it'll solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will give that a go, however I am not there now until next week, I have also been looking into Windows Short (8.3) Filenames issues and I will also try and disable them and remove them as per this link: https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/windows-short-8-3-filenames-web-security-problem/